# "There is an error" when clicking on some Silverstripe admin pages

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm trying to fix a problem with some Silverstripe admin pages. Everytime when I click on Cart or Example product page, the message - "There is an error" pops up, and the page wouldn't show. Please see the attached image.

[image]

As you can see page Cart and example product's icons are different from the rest. I didn't write the code myself and I've never experienced this before, so any suggestion on where I should start to tackle the problem would be appreciated.

I can copy some code here if you can tell me which part. Thank you very much for your time.

Regards
Sam

Firefox console message when click on the Cart page.

[image]

Additional error message under console response tab:

```
ERROR [User Error]: Bad class to singleton() - ProductImageObject
IN POST /admin/getitem?ID=17&ajax=1
Line 334 in /home/xxx/subdomains/xxx/sapphire/core/Core.php

Source
======
  325:  *
  326:  * @param string $className
  327:  * @return Object
  328:  */
  329: function singleton($className) {
  330:  global $_SINGLETONS;
  331:  if(!isset($className)) user_error("singleton() Called without a class", E_USER_ERROR);
  332:  if(!is_string($className)) user_error("singleton() passed bad class_name: " .
   var_export($className,true), E_USER_ERROR);
  333:  if(!isset($_SINGLETONS[$className])) {
* 334:      if(!class_exists($className)) user_error("Bad class to singleton() - $className",
   E_USER_ERROR);
  335:      $_SINGLETONS[$className] = Object::strong_create($className,null, true);
  336:      if(!$_SINGLETONS[$className]) user_error("singleton() Unknown class '$className'", E_USER_ERROR);
  337:  }
  338:  return $_SINGLETONS[$className];
  339: }
  340: 

Trace
=====
<ul>user_error(Bad class to singleton() - ProductImageObject,256)
line 334 of Core.php

singleton(ProductImageObject)
line 96 of DataObjectManager.php

DataObjectManager->__construct(Product,ProductImages,ProductImageObject,Array,getCMSFields_forPopup,,Created DESC,)
line 48 of FileDataObjectManager.php

FileDataObjectManager->__construct(Product,ProductImages,ProductImageObject,ProductImage,Array,getCMSFields_forPopup)
line 125 of Product.php

Product->getCMSFields(CMSMain)
line 444 of CMSMain.php

CMSMain->getEditForm(17)
line 1021 of LeftAndMain.php

LeftAndMain->EditForm()
line 382 of LeftAndMain.php

LeftAndMain->getitem(SS_HTTPRequest)
line 193 of Controller.php

Controller->handleAction(SS_HTTPRequest)
line 137 of RequestHandler.php

RequestHandler->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest)
line 147 of Controller.php

Controller->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest)
line 281 of Director.php

Director::handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,Session)
line 124 of Director.php

Director::direct(/admin/getitem)
line 127 of main.php

</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have Firebug so you can see what errors the console is displaying? Are you able to view the log files on the server?

Comment: Hi Brandon, thanks for your reply, I have uploaded the console image above, any ideas? Sorry where do i view the log files? I'm new to this, any help is appreciated. thanks, S

Comment: click on the + sign before the "POST", and then look at the reponse tab (or the html tab). What do you see?

Comment: Hi Greg, it says There has been an error, nothing else. Any other sources you need? Thank you.

Comment: as @xeera mentions below, put your site in dev mode (you could just add '?isDev=1' to your admin url), and post the POST entry here again (open the response tab as proposed above!)

Comment: Thanks for following it up, I have added the error message under console and response when I clicked on the Cart page in admin. Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried adding '?flush=All' to the admin url?
in case that doesn't help, you should post some code excerpt (a zip file). the problem might be with the relation of your cart page (see the page type when hovering over it in the cms) to the 'ProductImageObject' objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can have many reasons, try 2 things to get started:

1) Put your site into development mode (if it isn't already): http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/topics/debugging#dev-mode

2) Log errors (server-side): http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/topics/error-handling#filesystem-logs

This will help you with server-side errors (and "there has been an error/500" sounds a lot like it) - you should find an entry related to it in the log file. If it's just a client-side / JS thing, you'll need to dive deeper into firebug...

And don't worry about the icons in the page tree, this is a feature (see http://www.ssbits.com/snippets/2009/spice-up-your-cms-sitetree/ for a brief description).

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you have to check the PHP class that defines your Cart Page. Most probably, you have misspelled or mistyped something.

> Bad class to singleton() - ProductImageObject

This is our clue. Try checking line 125 of Product.php.